# Execute javascript if client clicks on stop loading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php that does something like this (it takes 5 sec for every iteration, not like the ex. below)

```
for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++){
echo '<span>number is '.$i.'</span><br>';
flush();
ob_flush();
}
```

I'm lazy so I want to copy the text with 1 click, so I use this jquery script

```
<script src="jquery-3.6.1.min.js">
</script><script>$("span").click(function (e) { var clickedCell = $(e.target).closest("span"); navigator.clipboard.writeText(clickedCell.text());});</script>
```

I tried to echo the script at beginning, before the for loop, this automatically puts the script in head section, but it does not work. like so

```
echo '<script src="jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script><script>$("span").click(function (e) { var clickedCell = $(e.target).closest("span"); navigator.clipboard.writeText(clickedCell.text());});</script>';
flush();
ob_flush();

for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++){
echo '<span>number is '.$i.'</span><br>';
flush();
ob_flush();
}
```

I tried to put the script at the end of the for loop, like

```
for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++){
echo '<span>number is '.$i.'</span><br>';
flush();
ob_flush();}
echo '<script src="jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script><script>$("span").click(function (e) { var clickedCell = $(e.target).closest("span"); navigator.clipboard.writeText(clickedCell.text());});</script>';
```

This works only after the for loop ends, but not as long as the page is loading (for loop did not end) or if I click on x on page loading on the browser to stop the loading of the page (if I found something interesting at i=25 and I do not want to execute the script further)

So, how can I make the script work even if the browser did not fully load or if I manually cancel the loading of the page from the browser (click on x to cancel the loading)

Comment: put it at the top, but wrap the script tag that has `$("span"). ...` in it with `$(function(){  [code goes here]   });` so that it defers looking for elements to bind events unto until the page is loaded (more or less).

Comment: yes, put it at answers so I can aword you the answer echo '<script src="jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script><script>$(function(){  $("span").click(function (e) { var clickedCell = $(e.target).closest("span"); navigator.clipboard.writeText(clickedCell.text());});   });</script>';
flush();
    ob_flush();for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++){
echo '<span>number is '.$i.'</span><br>';
flush();
ob_flush();}